# Unable to set class name dynamically

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have input element for which I am setting class Name dynamically by calling a function as follows :

```
<div className={styles1.col75}>
           <input className={this.errorClass(this.state.errors["name"])} type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={this.updateParam} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Your full name.."/>
           <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["name"]}</span>
         </div>
```

You can check in the above code className={this.errorClass(this.state.errors["name"])}

errorClass function is defined as follows :

```
errorClass(error) {
    if(error && error.length > 0){
      return 'error';
    }else{
      return '';
    }
  }
```

I have defined error class in main.css as follows :

```
.error{
     border: 2px solid red;
   }
```

I have imported main.css as follows :

```
import styles1 from '../css/main.css';
```

I am able to see the correct class been set using browser inspect element feature as this

```
<input type="text" class="error" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your full name..">
```

But I do not see class definition of error in the browser because of which required effect is not been applied on the input element.

Can someone guide?

[image]

Comment: Can you also add your project structure? It looks like there is a mistake while importing the css

Comment: added file structure. Code is been written in Register.js

Comment: Just try using -------------> import '../css/main.css';

Comment: No this did not solve the problem. File import is correct and using it in existing file.

Comment: by the way, your `errorClass`  function could be simplified to just `error ? 'error' : ''`. Note that empty strings are falsy in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample demo which is working all fine. In the above demo when you clear the text field value the error class will be applied dynamically.

I'm adding the code snippet below

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      errors : {"name" : ""},
      name : "Initial Value"
    }
    this.updateParam = this.updateParam.bind(this);
  }

  updateParam(event){
    this.setState({name : event.target.value});
    if(event.target.value === ""){
      this.setState({errors : {"name" : "Error Occured"}});
    }
  }

  errorClass(error) {
    if(error && error.length > 0){
      return 'error';
    }else{
      return '';
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <div> Hello World
          <div className="sample">
           <input className={this.errorClass(this.state.errors["name"])} type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={this.updateParam} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Your full name.."/>
           <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["name"]}</span>
         </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

And in the App.css file I have this css code

```css
.error{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

The above code works well for me. Please note that this snippet will not directly run here since I have not included the react script. However, you can try this code on your machine.

Thanks